# Switch Case with parameter passed from VBA - parameter not compatible

Tags: c++, vba, if-statement, dll, switch-statement

this is an odd behaviour which I encouter.
I have a Visual Basic Interface for the User.

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub getPEC _
Lib "C:\Users\...somePath...\OPunit0011PUMP.dll" _
(ByVal typeOfPump As Integer, _
ByVal outflow As Double, _
ByRef pec As Double, _
ByRef RV As Integer)
```

The user specifies a pump by the integer typeOfPump. I pass this parameter as ByVal typeOfPump into my C++ DLL.
Here according to which pump it is some predeclared parameters a,...g are initialized using switch case

```
extern "C"

{

double PEC_backUp;

void __stdcall getPEC(int typeOfPump, double outflow, double &PEC, int &RV)
{
    //polynomal trendline for different pumps
    //y = a x^6 + b x^5 + c x^4 + d x^3 + e x^2 + f x^1 + g x^0
    if (typeOfPump < 1)
    {
        RV = -1;
        return;
    }

    double a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
#pragma region switch case
    switch (typeOfPump)
    {

        //150 bar
    case 1:
        a = 1.1186E-08;
        b = -1.49172E-05;
        //...
        break;
   case 2:
        //...
   }
```

My problem is that switch case does NOT work. My default value is set to nine, but also every other case does NOT work. It simply neglects the switch case code.
Note also: The same odd behaviour can be seen in the If condition:

```
if (typeOfPump > 1)
    {
        RV = -1;
        return;
    }
```

Despite the fact that typeOfPump is assigned to **NINE** which is obviously bigger than one my function getPEC does not return at this point. On the other hand if I write

```
if (typeOfPump < 1)
        {
            RV = -1;
            return;
        }
```

my function will return here. I then assigned the value of typeOfPump to RV to monitor it in VBA and RV was set to nine.

Moreover, to make things even stranger it automatically changes the value of pec to 7.00000000005821 (using watch function of VBA) when it returns with RV = -1.

I guess my parameter are somehow not compatible for operations in my DLL. Did anyone see this before and how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** I can do operations like

```
RV = typeOfPump * (int)outflow;
```

and obtain correct values. However, pec still shows some change in its value.

**SCD EDIT:** I have 64bit, Excel is 32bit, I'm compiling with x86.
I wrote a similar program on another computer 64bit, Excel 64bit, compiling with x64. There it worked!

**3rd EDIT:** integer of value **9** in VBA results in **-65526** in C++ environment, given size of integer in my C++ environment is 4byte. Assuming range of 16bit variable for integer is **−32,768 to 32,767**. Doubling 32,767 and subtracting **9** leads to **65525**.

Comment: I think this __is__ a VBA question, not VB.net: `PtrSafe` is a VBA keyword, used to mark functions that can be safely called from 64-bit Excel as far as I can see. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx for 32/64-bit compatibility.

Comment: Correct, OP also made an edit removed my comment.

Comment: A VBA `Integer` is 16 bits. Have you printed out `typeOfPump` in the dll and looked at its value?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. My MessageBox prints: **-65526** if input value is **9**.

Comment: In my case the integer variable in the DLL comprises 4 bytes (sizeof operator used). I also read VBA's integer has 32 bit, so 4 bytes, respectively (compare: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/06bkb8w2.aspx) or am I mislead at some point. Anyway, how can I prevent this error?

Comment: Interestingly, (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)) 16 bit would mean a range of **−32,768 to 32,767**. Doubling 32767 and subtract nine from the result comes up with -65526. Hence, it seems this problem is related to size-of-integer-differences.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you're not sure why your code isn't working, print out the values that you are sure of, and see if they are actually what you think they are. Especially if mixing 32bit and 64 bit code. There are all kinds of compiler options which will affect the data format when it's used.

Write your code as a standalone exe, make sure that it works; write the dll with handshaking as simply as possible, make sure that works, and then make your exe a dll. You're trying to do too much in one step.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, you should post it in the comment section.